# Using Sentry 2, what is the difference between authenticate() and login()?

Tags: laravel-4, cartalyst-sentry

Using Cartalys Sentry 2, and I can't seem to find any documentation on the difference between the authenticate() and login() methods, nor when to use one versus the other. Any guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that `authenticate` will receive an array of credentials:

```
// Login credentials
$credentials = array(
    'email'    => 'john.doe@example.com',
    'password' => 'password',
);

// Authenticate the user
$user = Sentry::authenticate($credentials, false);
```

And the `login` method receives an $user object

```
// Find the user using the user id
$user = Sentry::findUserById(1);

// Log the user in
Sentry::login($user, false);
```

Comment: Thanks. Would there be any usage scenarios for using one vs the other?

Comment: It's really up to what you need at the moment. I use the authenticate method when a user enters their information in a form.
As for the login method, we have a super user account that can login with any user of the database. In that case, since you don't know the user's password, this login method is useful.